# If A and B are two Matrices , than find $(A-B)^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

IF $A$ and $B$ are two matrices, find $(A-B)^2$.

My first solution was :
$$
A^2 - 2AB + B^2.
$$

My second solution was :
$$
(A-B)(A-B) \\
A^2 - AB - BA + A^2
$$

Is one of them correct ? or both of them are incorrect ?

Comment: Are you trying to find $(A + B)^2$ or $(A - B)^2$? You need to edit your post to make it clear. As it stands, both your answers are wrong if you are trying to find $(A + B)^2$

Answer (score 9):

$A^2 - 2AB + B^2$ is not true for all matrices.

$A^2 - AB - BA + B^2$ is correct.

You need to know that $AB = BA$ in order to conclude that $(A-B)^2 = A^2 - 2AB + B^2$.

Answer (score 6):

$(A-B)^2=(A-B)(A-B)=A(A-B)-B(A-B)=A^2-AB-BA+B^2$. In general $AB\not=BA$.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the second solution is correct (with $B^2$ instead of $A^2$ at the end) but the first one is incorrect because matrix multiplication isn't commutative.

Comment: I meant that .. Thanks